# Show that $\int_0^\sqrt{\pi} e^{-x^2}\sin(x^2)dx>\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}e^{-\pi}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Please solve it with basic multivariate calculus skills.
I attempted multiple times but couldn't prove it without using WolframAlpha.

**Motivation** : note that the RHS bounds from above $$\int_{\sqrt\pi}^\infty |e^{-x^2}\sin(x^2)| dx$$, so these two observations together prove the fact that $$ \int_{0}^\infty e^{-x^2}\sin(x^2)>0.$$

Comment: Note that LHS$=0.290508$ and RHS$=0.0382973$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Denoting your integral by $I$, we have
  $$ I \ge \frac1{\sqrt\pi} \int_0^{\sqrt\pi} xe^{-x^2}\sin(x^2)\,dx 
   = \frac1{2\sqrt\pi} \int_0^{\pi} e^{-y}\sin(y)\,dy $$
(where the equality comes from the substitution $y=x^2$).
The integral in the RHS is easily computed using double integration by parts, and is equal to $(1+e^{-\pi})/2$. Consequently,
  $$ I \ge \frac{1+e^{-\pi}}{4\sqrt\pi} > \frac{\sqrt\pi}2 e^{-\pi} $$
(in fact, $(1+e^{-\pi})/4\sqrt\pi\approx 0.1471$, while $\frac{\sqrt\pi}2 e^{-\pi}\approx 0.0383$).

Comment: Could you please explain where the first $\geq$ come from? Is that a consequence of Holder's inequality?

Comment: @ZXW: This is much simpler: just notice that $\frac1{\sqrt\pi}\cdot x\le 1$ for all $x$ in the integration range $0\le x\le\sqrt\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Since both of those functions wont go to zero, no matter how many time you integrate them, I would try doing integration by parts twice and then comparing the original integrand to your result, and solve for the integral algebraically.